# scroll the list until you find the object with the corresponding id - C#

Tags: c#, list, recursion, parent-child

I have a list like this ( already open with the visual studio debugger ) :

[image]

As you can see the list is made ​​up of other objects of the same type list , my need is to run through all the children , regardless by the Index and verify that the ***FID*** of that object is the same as the one passed by the UI . Once you found matching server that returns the same object .

***i can try this for test, 
but considering I only top-level items , those with index 0 , does not flow in all:***

```
AttachmentFolders childWithId17 = ApplicationContext.Instance.companyList[0].AttachmentFolders.SelectMany(parent => parent.AttachmentFolder)
                             .FirstOrDefault(child => child.FID == "835A09A2-9D60-46CC-A2BE-D4CBC4C81860");
```

***another picture to better understand***

[image]

in fact, I get a list with many elements and should scroll it all , even in responsive manner to be able to return the object that corresponds to that AttachmentFolders ***FID*** .

***class structure:***

```
public class AttachmentFolders
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public String FID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String CPID { get; set; }
        public String ParentFID { get; set; }

            public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
            public List<AttachmentFolders> AttachmentFolder { get; set; }
        }

public class Attachment
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public String ATID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String CreatorID { get; set; }
        public String FID { get; set; }
        public String Extension { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public String CPID { get; set; }
        public int FileSize { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public int AttachmentType { get; set; }
        public int ValidityType { get; set; }
        public List<Revisions> Revisions { get; set; }
        public String AWID { get; set; }
        public String WAID { get; set; }
        public String WatermarkPositions { get; set; }
        public Boolean Serveroffline { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsFavourite { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastOpenDate { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public String CreatorFirstName { get; set; }
        public String CreatorLastName { get; set; }
        public String ModifiedByFirstName { get; set; }
        public String ModifiedByLastName { get; set; }
        public String[] Capabilities { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you all.

Comment: I can't recreate your class structure. Could you please show us how are your classes designed?

Comment: i have add the two class of the structure, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like the `SelectDeep` extension as in this Marc's answer: [Expressing recursion in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732281/expressing-recursion-in-linq/793531#793531)

and then use it in your code instead of `SelectMany`:

```
AttachmentFolders child = companyList[0].AttachmentFolders
    .SelectDeep(parent => parent.AttachmentFolder)
    .FirstOrDefault(child => child.FID == "835A09A2-9D60-46CC-A2BE-D4CBC4C81860");
```

The `SelectDeep` method looks as follows:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectDeep<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector) {
        foreach (T item in source) {
            yield return item;
            foreach (T subItem in SelectDeep(selector(item), selector)) {
                yield return subItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to add SelectDeep ? i don't have definition in visual studio

Comment: forgive me , but I can not understand the code , that is, how to apply , can you clarify ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer Definition of function `SelectDeep` is in my answer. You can use it to return all of the items from the nested structure (tree). Just use this function intead of `SelectMany`.

Comment: i have this error on SelectDeep: Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class; EnumerableExtensions is a nested class, how to solve ? if possible, thanks

Comment: @Mr.Developer You can't place the `EnumerableExtensions` class within another class. It must be placed at top level, outside of any class.

Comment: What ... a careless mistake by newbies , I put it out of the classroom and now it works . Thanks for your patience. Everything works

Answer (score -1):

This is a typical recursion case. You could try searching a flattened tree structure, as done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586745/2979473) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586590/2979473) answer.

If you experience slow performance of this solution, I would think about creating a helper `Dictionary<string, AttachmentFolders>` object, which would hold all (sub)folder references for quick access, e.g.

```
IEnumerable<AttachmentFolders> Flatten(AttachmentFolders f)
{
    var fs = new[] { f };
    return f.Children == null? fs : fs.Concat(f.Children.SelectMany(Flatten));
}

Dictionary<string, AttachmentFolders> GenerateCache(AttachmentFolders firstFolder)
{
    return Flatten(firstFolder).ToDictionary(f => f.FID, f => f);
}
```

Then, one-time at start:

```
Dictionary<string, AttachmentFolders> Cache = GenerateCache(firstFolder);
```

And each time a request is made:

```
if(Cache.ContainsKey(fid)) return Cache[fid];
else throw new Exception("Handle not found FID here");
```

Comment: what is it GenerateCache ?

Comment: Something like the function I have now edited into my answer.

Comment: Also it works but I preferred to use the @romanoza solution is one that does more to my case with the extension . Thanks for your help. I'll put you up on the answer.